# Import data for local mongodb from WiredTiger shard archive

Tags: mongodb, sharding, wiredtiger

I've downloaded an archive with a shard of database from cloud.mongodb.
There is a folder with many **.wt** files inside this archive.
But I couldn't find a way to replicate this data to my local machine.
I tried Studio3T but it seems that such format is not supported for data import.
I'm new to sharding and cloud storage so probably I misunderstood something.
What am I missing? Is that even possible to import such backup file to local instance?
There are also **.bson** file and some **.sh** script. Screenshot attached [shard_folder_files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeOeC.png)

Answer (score 0):

You would run `mongod` of the same version that the backup is from, and point it to this data directory using `--dbpath` option.